# Azure components connectivity check

Tags: azure, connections, application-insights

My Project involves various azure products like web job, Event hub, table storage, blob storage etc.

I need to create a Live dashboard which shows the connectivity of the various components.

Eg., one web job get data from event hub, and moves it to Table storage, blob storgae and also to an event hub.

I need to check the connectivity of web job --> event hub, web job to table storage etc. Is this possible using application insights or any azure product.
what are the other tools available.

Answer (score 1):

Tools like application insights can only show what you tell it to. Application insights looks at the data coming out of your app and environment and displays and offer suggestions on it. It will show you things like slow requests, which could indicate slow connectivity between app and event hub etc, but ideally, you'll build some telemetry into your app that will detect this, and have app insights trigger alerts based off this.

Comment: Thank you. I see, what application insights can do.